# WordPress / PhpStorm script corruption

Tags: php, wordpress, webserver, phpstorm

When I access certain pages on the WP admin panel, it does not load due to corrupt script files.

I have downloaded WordPress and opened it as a project in PhpStorm (2021.1). I am using PHP 7.4.9 (installed via HomeBrew) and the built-in web server.

I have confirmed that the original script files are not corrupt.
When the page loads the scripts via load-scripts.php (`load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.7.1`), which returns a bunch of concatenated scripts, the response contains additional bytes in the middle.

```
...{S.removeAttr(this,e)})}}�a����),S.extend...
```

I opened the file and did a hexdump to identify what they were:

```
000fff0 73 2c 65 29 7d 29 7d 7d 01 06 00 40 ef bf bd ef
0010000 bf bd 00 00 29 2c 53 2e 65 78 74 65 6e 64 28 7b
```

Around the 64KiB mark, there are some unexpected bytes being inserted (`01 06 00 40 ef bf bd ef`) and (`bf bd 00 00`).

This obviously makes the JavaScript unusable. I'd like to know if I need to configure PHP or the built-in web server in a special way that this doesn't happen. Is it some binary chunking done by the web server? I'm not sure, but it makes WP unusable right now.

Comment: TBH: no clues on my end right now. I may only suggest to try a proper Apache from some pre-configured stack (e.g. XAMPP or MAMP) and see how it behaves there to see if it's a PHP or a web server config issue. You may also want to debug/edit that script and dump the result into a local file before sending the result to a browser -- to see if such extra stuff is already present there or not. May also check the file content once that script loads individual files into a memory (to see where such corruption might be happening).

Comment: Just a guess, but might it be an issue of file encoding? Is UTF-8 set properly or might the encoding be off?

Comment: It seems to be a built-in web server bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43701

Comment: Thanks, I posted that as an answer. Nothing else we can do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug/issue with the built-in web server of PHPStorm:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43701